# store value from ajax succes into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am struggling with an issue to solve my problem for hours already!
I want to do store the success values of my ajax request in a global var in my JS code. While AJAX is asynchron, it doesn't work to the time I would like it to work, I know that already. The problem is: How can I still solve the problem, that I get the data in a array/var from the success?
I read and tried a lot, but nothing worked.

That's my code snip:

```
var result = "";
function InitIndexIDs(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/appendTable.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
              result = data 
              console.log(result) // success
        },

    });

}

console.log(result) // ---> ""
```

I have read about setting it to asynchron, which would work, but is supposed to be a bad idea, because it would trigger more problems, than solve it.

So what can I do, to solve my Problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: The codes seems right. What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: The last "console.log(result)" will indeed have nothing stored, but the one in the callback should be fine.